# Need help getting the mean of a column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

So I've been trying to figure out this problem with a data frame called life_expectancy.

> Write a function `get_col_mean()` that takes in a column name and a data frame
>   
>   and returns the mean of that column. Make sure to properly handle NA values

```
get_col_mean <- function(col_name, data_set) {
  return(mean(data_set[,col_name], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

> Create a list `col_means` that has the mean value of each column in the
>   
>   data frame (except the `Country` column). You should use your function above.

```
years <- life_exp[0,-1]
col_means <- lapply(years, get_col_mean, data_set = life_exp)
print(col_means)
```

I expect it to output a list of the length "years" and for each year, to output the mean of the column for that year as well. But I get a list with the value NA under each year instead of the mean. And the error:

```
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: Try `sapply(life_exp[,-col_number_for_country],mean)`? You can "automate" column number generation by using such functions as `which` and `*names`.

Comment: @NelsonGon while this worked, I need to use the function that I was asked to write `get_col_mean`

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. So what did you try to fix it? Any research?